# listview to open new page loading xml into new listview with links to sub page in jquery mobile

Tags: jquery, xml, listview, jquery-mobile-listview

I am a total noob to jquery and am asking for some help in what the best way would be to code a list that displays a collection of buttons that point to lists that are created by xml and lead to a display page when clicked.

the idea is that you come onto the page, you pick an area of interest (listview), it loads the xml and displays that areas list of content (listview). You click on a list item and it takes you to a content page where text, video etc is displayed. I have 20 feeds I have to deal with.

I can get one xml feed to work but have had a hard time understanding how to deal with multiple xml feeds and how to call them and display them. Any examples would be very helpful and appreciated.

Here is what I have

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
        <head>
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
        <title></title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="js/jquery.mobile-1.1.0.min.css" />
        <script src="js/jquery-1.8.0.min.js"></script>
        <script src="js/jquery.mobile-1.1.0.min.js"></script>
        <script src="loader.js"></script>
        </head>
        <body>
        <div data-role="page" id="photos">
          <header data-role="header">
            <h2>DA News</h2>
          </header>
          <div data-role="content">
            <ul data-role="listview" data-filter="true">
              <li> <a href="#" id="btn">
                <h2>The Channel News</h2>
                <img src="images/icon_podcast-TCN_News.jpg" alt="TCN" />
                <p>The lastest headlines from around the gloab</p>
                </a> </li>
              <li> <a href="#mainPage">
                <h2>Staff Podcast</h2>
                <img src="images/icon_podcast-Stoff.jpg" alt="Staff Podcast" />
                <p>Staff Offical Podcast</p>
                </a> </li>
              <li> <a href="#mainPage" >
                <h2>Space</h2>
                <img src="images/icon_podcast-space.jpg" alt="space" />
                <p>space stories</p>
                </a> </li>
            </ul>
          </div>
          <footer data-role="footer" data-position="fixed">
            <nav data-role="navbar">
              <ul>
                <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
                <li><a href="#list">list</a>
                <li><a href="#info">Info</a></li>
              </ul>
            </nav>
          </footer>
        </div>
        <!-- end of buttons -->

        <div data-role="page" data-rel="dialog" id="mainPage">
          <header data-role="header">
            <h1>tpc news</h1>
          </header>
          <footer data-role="footer" data-position="fixed">
            <nav data-role="navbar">
              <ul>
                <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
                <li><a href="#list">list</a>
                <li><a href="#info">Info</a></li>
              </ul>
            </nav>
          </footer>
        </div>
        <!-- mainPage -->
        </div>
        <div data-role="page" id="contentPage">
          <div data-role="header">
            <h1>TC News</h1>
          </div>
          <div data-role="content" data-theme="a" id="entryText" style="text-align:center";> </div>
          <footer data-role="footer" data-theme="a" data-position="fixed">
            <nav data-role="navbar">
              <ul>
                <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
                <li><a href="#list">list</a>
                <li><a href="#info">Info</a></li>
              </ul>
            </nav>
          </footer>
        </div>
        <!-- contentPage -->

        </div>
</body>
        </html>
<scriptfile starts here ----loader.js------>
/*$(document).on('click','a#btn',function(){
    var xmlq = $("http://foo.xml").val();
$.mobile.changePage("#mainPage")
});*/


    var xml;
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $.ajax({
            type: "GET",
            url: "http://foo.xml",
            dataType: "xml",
            success: xmlParser
        });
    });
        function xmlParser(data) {
            xml = data;

            $('#load').fadeOut();

            $(xml).find("item").each(function () {
                title = $(this).attr("title");

                var title = $(this).find("title").text();
                var description = $(this).find("description").text();
                var pubDate = $(this).find("pubDate").text();
                var link = $(this).find("link").text();




    $("#list").append('
    <li>
          <h3 id="title">' + title + '</h3>
          <ul>
        <li>description: '+ description + '</li>
        <li>pubDate: '+ pubDate + '</li>
        <li>link: '+ link + '</li>
      </ul>
        </li>
    ');

                $('#list').listview('refresh'); 
            });

        }
```

Comment: Can you show us the code for the one that works?

Comment: I started to try and change the xml url value as you can see at the top of the js file and the first button. Didn't get that to work either. Thanks for the help